# Why is my ClaimsIdentity IsAuthenticated always false (for web api Authorize filter)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, asp.net-4.5

In a Web API project I am overriding the normal authentication process to check tokens instead. The code looks something like this:

```cs
if ( true ) // validate the token or whatever here
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add( new Claim( ClaimTypes.Name, "MyUser" ) );
    claims.Add( new Claim( ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "MyUserID" ) );
    claims.Add( new Claim( ClaimTypes.Role, "MyRole" ) );

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity( claims );

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal( new[] { claimsIdentity } );
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

And then later when I apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to a controller, it fails to authorize.

Debug code confirms the same behavior:

```cs
// ALWAYS FALSE!
if ( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) {
    // do something
}
```

Why does it think the user is not authenticated even though I've constructed a valid ClaimsIdentity and assigned it to the thread?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The problem is because of a breaking change in .Net 4.5. As explained by [this article](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/09/24/claimsidentity-isauthenticated-and-authenticationtype-in-net-4-5/), simply constructing a claims identity no longer makes it IsAuthenticated return true. Instead, you need to pass some string (doesn't matter what) into the constructor.

So this line in the above code:

```cs
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity( claims );
```

Becomes this:

```cs
// exact string doesn't matter
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity( claims, "CustomApiKeyAuth" );
```

And the problem is solved. **Update:** see other answer from Leo. The exact AuthenticationType value may or may not be important depending on what else you have in your auth pipeline.

Update 2: as suggested by Robin van der Knaap in the comments, one of the `System.Security.Claims.AuthenticationTypes` values might be appropriate.

```cs
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity( claims, AuthenticationTypes.Password );

// and elsewhere in your application...
if (User.Identity.AuthenticationType == AuthenticationTypes.Password) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Although you could add any string, according to MSDN this should typically be one of the values defined in the AuthenticationTypes class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.authenticationtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Example: var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity( claims, AuthenticationTypes.Password );

Comment: The value of the string becomes visible in User.Identity.AuthenticationType

Comment: Wow that is really obscure!  Thanks for sharing this here!  I was stuck for over an hour.

Answer (score 20):

While the provided answer has some validity in it, it is not entirely correct. You can't assume that just adding any string will magically work. As stated in one of the comment, this string must match one of the [`AuthenticationTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.authenticationtypes(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration which in turn must match the one specified in the OWIN authentication/authorization middleware....for example...

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions serverOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Password,
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                Provider = new AppAuthServerProvider()
            };


            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(serverOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Password
                });            
        }
```

However, in the above scenario it wouldn't matter much. But, if you are using more authentication/authorization levels the claims will be associated to the one that matches the same `AuthenticationType`...another example is when you use cookie authentication...

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login")
            });
        }
```

where `AuthenticationType` describes the name of the cookie, since your app may have obtained other cookies from other providers it is important that you set the `AuthenticationType` when instantiating the claims in order to associate then to the correct cookie

Comment: In .NET Core you can use constants as `AuthenticationType`, e.g. [CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationdefaults.authenticationscheme) or [JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerdefaults.authenticationscheme).

Comment: Note, when creating `ClaimsIdentity`, you need to pass the schema name as the `AuthenticationType` (like `new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationScheme)`). Otherwise the `IsAuthenticated` flag on the identity is gonna be `false`. I got caught on the same non-intuitive problem twice over last 2 years and this answer helped me again. Can't upvote this answer twice unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexKlaus thanks for your input, it's very valuable. I even thought of updating the answer a couple of years ago but then I realized the original question was "pre-.NET Core" and it's explicitly targeting ASP.NET 4.5. So, I'll leave it as it is for now