# Asp.Net MVC 6 Cookie Authentication - Authorization fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create asp.net core mvc 6 app using [Cookie Middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html) authentication. 
My code compiles without errors, but even after successful login i'm not authorized user

Here's my startup.cs configuration

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "CookieAuth";
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;

        });
```

Also login action in my controller:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {

        User foundUser = _userManager.findUser(model.UserName, model.Password);


        if (foundUser != null)
        {
            List<Claim> userClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("userId", Convert.ToString(foundUser.UserID)),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, foundUser.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Convert.ToString(foundUser.RoleID))
            };

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims));
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("CookieAuth", principal);


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And finally Dashboard/Index action

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I put some breakpoints in login action and everything seems works fine.
Cookie is also set correctly.

And now I don't know way i can't go to dashboard/index after sign in.
Each time i'm redirected to /Account/Login/ due to configuration settings

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you construct your `ClaimsIdentity` in your login, you need to use a different constructor that specifies the `authenticationType`.

Instead of

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims));
```

You should do:

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "local"));
```

> It is now possible to create a ClaimsIdentity that has claims, but
>   having IsAuthenticated set to false. Actually this is the default now...
>
> To have IsAuthenticated set to true, you need to specify an authentication type

I got this info from Dominick Baier's blog [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/09/24/claimsidentity-isauthenticated-and-authenticationtype-in-net-4-5/).

There is also a great example of using the cookie middleware [here](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/tree/master/Cookies/src/AspNetCoreAuthentication), also by (the legendary) Dominick Baier / leastprivilege.

**EDIT:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30430228/3130094) contains more information about what *should* be used for the `authenticationType` string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Beacause of one param I lost 2h of my life :(

Comment: Well deserved up-vote, thank you for the answer! 2+ hours lost, but at least I know why!

Comment: Spent 4 hours on this. Thanks. What should be set for the `authenticationType` parameter? Is it "Cookie", "JWT" or the scheme used or anything?

Comment: @Omar - there is some more information here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30430228/3130094

Comment: Last link is broken, was most likely pointing to https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/tree/master/Cookies/src/AspNetCoreAuthentication

Comment: Thank you! I lost 3h with this problem.