# AuthenticationHandler ending request prematurely

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a .net core AuthenticationHandler with some custom logic.  Whenever I make a request to the page everything in the auth handler runs fine but it returns a 200 without actually executing the code for my end controller.  I've distilled it down to this simplified version.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication("Dummy")
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, DummyAuthHandler>("Dummy", null);
    ...
```

My handler:

```
public class DummyAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public DummyAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : 
            base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        => Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(
               new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(), "Dummy")));

    protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)  
        => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I'm thinking I'm missing one of the methods needed to tell the framework to continue processing the request, and not to just think my authentication handler wants the page redirected.  Maybe I even need to add a call to next() somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it thanks to [this](https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authorisation-in-asp-net-core/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254796/why-is-my-claimsidentity-isauthenticated-always-false-for-web-api-authorize-fil)... the ClaimsIdentity was returning IsAuthenticated = False, which is why I thought I needed the HandleChallengeAsync in the first place.  Here's what the fixed handler looks like:

```
public class DummyAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public DummyAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : 
            base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        => Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(
               new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(
                   new ClaimsIdentity("abc")), "Dummy")));
}
```