# .Net Core 2.0 Authorization always returning 401

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

After adding `[Authorize]` to a controller, I'm always getting a 401 from it. While debugging, I see the `return AuthenticateResult.Success` being reached, but the code of the controller never is.
What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code for my Startup class and Custom auth classes.

---

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Custom Scheme";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Custom Scheme";
        }).AddCustomAuth(o => { });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
        app.UseRewriter(options);

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CustomAuthOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; set; }

    public CustomAuthOptions()
    {

    }
}

public static class CustomAuthExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<CustomAuthOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        return builder.AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthHandler>("Custom Scheme", "Custom Auth", configureOptions);
    }
}

internal class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {

    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        string token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Failing string");

        // Using external service to validate token and get user id
        int Id = GetUserId(token);

        return AuthenticateResult.Success(
            new AuthenticationTicket(
                new ClaimsPrincipal(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(
                        new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, Id.ToString()) })),
                        Scheme.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable logging and see what the internal system is doing, you'll likely see some helpful information there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way you create an instance of `ClaimsIdentity` in `CustomAuthHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()`. The value of `principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will be `false` that makes `AuthorizeAttribute` to consider your request unathorized.

The reason why `IsAuthenticated` is set to false is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254796/why-is-my-claimsidentity-isauthenticated-always-false-for-web-api-authorize-fil) in detail. To fix it, just use `ClaimsIdentity` constructor overload that takes `authenticationType`:

```
return AuthenticateResult.Success(
    new AuthenticationTicket(
        new ClaimsPrincipal(
            new ClaimsIdentity(
                new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, Id.ToString()) }, Scheme.Name)),
        Scheme.Name));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i was creating the list of claims with the `ClaimType.AuthenticationScheme` in it but the Authorization was failing, after Searching a LOT your answer just solved my problem (and i'm on ASP.net core 2.1)