# Custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` Authentication Failing

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a custom `ApiAuthenticationStateProvider` that after returning an `AuthenticationState` is still stating

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
```

Here is a simplified version of my `ApiAuthenticationStateProvider` that is failing:

```
public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
   public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Getting auth state...");
               
       var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "some.email@somewhere.com") };
       var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
       var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));

       return Task.FromResult(authState);
   }
}
```

I can tell from the `Console.WriteLine` that is using my custom provider but to provide full details, here is the code i used to add that in `Program.cs`:

`builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be resolved in this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254797/2682662

Basically when constructing the `ClaimsIdentity` you need to provide a string value for the authentication type.

```
var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Needs Auth Type Here"));
```

Comment: this answer appears to be most correct and links to an explanation of why the string 'auth type' is needed.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work on Blazor you will have to add `authenticationType` parameter value with `ClaimsIdentity` so your code will be changed to:

```
public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
   public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Getting auth state...");
               
       var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "some.email@somewhere.com") };
       var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationTypes.Password));
       var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));

       return Task.FromResult(authState);
   }
}
```

Notice the `AuthenticationTypes.Password` parameter for [ClaimsIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.authenticationtype?view=netcore-3.1).

This should be same in all places where `ClaimsIdentity` is constructed.

**Update:**
As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254796/why-is-my-claimsidentity-isauthenticated-always-false-for-web-api-authorize-fil/20254797#comment32952474_20254797), the value of authentication type should be one of the values defined in [`AuthenticationTypes` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.authenticationtypes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). *Updated the above code to use this class instead of a random auth type name.*

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1

your `ClaimsIdentity()` object instantiated with just the array of claims you create above appears correct in the documenation but providing a string of claim type (also in the documenation above) seems to actually be what is required

`var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Needs Auth Type Here"));`