# What is the preferred way to log-out a ClaimsIdentity (IsAuthenticated be false) in the eyes of Razor <AuthorizeView> tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, claims-based-identity

I am building a simple custom authentication method in my Blazor app. The several pages must be visible by a logged-in user through the Razor `<AuthorizeView>` attribute.

I am able to make it work by adding to the `ClaimsPrincipal` (obtained through the cascading `AuthenticationState`) a new `ClaimsIdentity` with a non-null authentication type (which is the info the `AuthorizeView` attribute uses when no `Role` or `Policy` is specified, see [Why is my ClaimsIdentity IsAuthenticated always false (for web api Authorize filter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254796/why-is-my-claimsidentity-isauthenticated-always-false-for-web-api-authorize-fil)). But then I am not able to remove that "authenticated" ClaimsIdentity when I want to "log-out" the user.

The workaround I have found is to plug a role called "loggedin" into the principal (through a new `ClaimsIdentity`) when he logs in, and unplug the role from the related `ClaimsIdentity` when he logs out. The Razor attribute controlling the visibility is then `<AuthorizeView Role="loggedin">`. I could also use a `Policy`, but both seem dirty to me, since here I only want the pages to be visible when the user is authenticated (instead of being "authorized", which roles and policies are made for, and I find is a concept that should be distincted from mere authentication). But maybe it's the right thing to do, I don't know.

So, what is the cleanest way to specify that a page should be visible only to authenticated users (without further conditions), and control the authentication state of the user, only using the Razor `AuthorizeView` attribute (and children), `ClaimsPrincipal` and `ClaimsIdentity` ?

Answer (score 1):

As you're question is light on code, here's a demo on how to do what I think you want.  This is based on Blazor Server.

It uses a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` to capture the original user and store the claims.  You can then construct your own `ClaimsIdentity` and `ClaimsPrincipal` using the captured claims.  If you principals have more that one identity you will need to code to capture that.

A custom authentication State Provider:

```cs
public class MyAuthenticationProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    ClaimsPrincipal? _user;
    IEnumerable<Claim>? _claims;

    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var authState = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

        var user = authState.User;
        if (user.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
            _claims = user.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims ?? Enumerable.Empty<Claim>();

        return authState;
    }

    public Task LogOutIdentityAsync()
    {
        _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(_claims, null));
        var newState = new AuthenticationState(_user);
        this.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult<AuthenticationState>(newState));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task LogInIdentityAsync()
    {
        _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(_claims, "nlm"));
        var newState = new AuthenticationState(_user);
        this.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult<AuthenticationState>(newState));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Registered:

```cs
// at the end of services definitions
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, MyAuthenticationProvider>();
```

A demo Layout to  toggle the authentication.

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authProvider

<PageTitle>BlazorApp1</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ToggleAuth">Toggle</button>
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

@code {
    bool _authState = true;

    void ToggleAuth()
    {
        if (_authState)
            ((MyAuthenticationProvider)_authProvider).LogOutIdentityAsync();
        else
            ((MyAuthenticationProvider)_authProvider).LogInIdentityAsync();

        _authState = !_authState;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. It seems that your solution is bigger on code that is mine. Also, since I don't see any AuthorizeView tag in your html code, would it work with it ? Does it recognize the custom AuthenticationStateProvider as being the one to use ? And what is the "LoginDisplay" tag in the code ? Is it just a placeholder tag or is it necessary ?

Comment: Forget the `LoginDisplay` it was just an artifact from where I copied the code.  It comes from a Github repo that demonstrates how to do Policy based Authorization - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization.

Comment: The `AuthorizeView` component implements ` [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState>? AuthenticationState { get; set; }
` - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b89e21ed72c7afd58fd372f7b8e6299847a8153a/src/Components/Authorization/src/AuthorizeViewCore.cs#L44 .  It works exactly the same.

Comment: Smaller code footprint isn't always better.  [Polite] "It seems that your solution is bigger on code that is mine" can't be judged as you don't show any code.  Your solution doesn't log the user out, just applies authorization through a Role.  To quote you "but both seem dirty to me".  What you implement depends on what your objectives are.  Your question was about logging out, not controlling access via roles or policies.

Comment: My code is really simple : when the user enters its credentials the app tests the (username, password) tuple against my authentication backend, and if it's a valid account then a new ClaimsIdentity having the claim {ClaimTypes.Role, "User"} is added to the ClaimsPrincipal obtained through the cascading AuthenticationState. However when I talk about "logging out", it's really in relation to <AuthorizeView>, it's about controlling the access without more conditions/rules than having a valid account.