# Blazor server - logout user from server side

Tags: authentication, blazor-server-side

Administrators can manage users in my application.
I´d now like to logout any user if i.e. an administrator locks or deletes a user.
Currently I´m using a custom RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider and a custom ITicketStore.
When I set the RevalidationInterval to a low value (i.e. 10 seconds), users get logged out when I delete or lock them (SecurityStamp changes or the ticket has been deleted from the ticketstore). But I don´t like ckecking the authenticationstate every 10 seconds. Is there a way to force Revalidation for only one user?

Thanks a lot for your help!

I already tried to use an event (i.e. UserChanged) from my AuthenticationService. But ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync expects a valid AuthenticationState which has to be constructed using a valid ClaimsPrincipal. I have no idea how to create a valid ClaimsPrincipal from any user (not the currently logged in user).

Comment: You can construct an *empty* AuthenticationState like this - `new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal())`.

Comment: See this answer on how to change authentication state on an identity - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840940/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-log-out-a-claimsidentity-isauthenticated-be-false/77842325#77842325

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This works, but only for the current logged in user. I wanted to logout another user (as an admin). I guess it´s not possiböle to force revalidation of the authenticationstate for another user.

Comment: I think it's possible.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I forcibly log out a User.

Take a look at this answer which demonstrates how to pass messages to all current logged in sessions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76171327/13065781

Using this approach you can create a singleton service that raises an event when a user has had their rights revoked.

You can add a component to the child content of `Router` in `Routes` i.e. is present on every page, that injects the service and registers for the event.  The handler checks the currently logged in user against the user Id in the notification and if it's them, takes action.  Maybe loads a content that forcibly revalidates them and tells them what's happened.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This could work. The only problem, in my oppinion is, that every logged in user receives the event then. No problem if there are only a few but if there are a lot of users? Does this use SignalR under the hood?

Comment: In Server mode, everything is in the Blazor Hub Session.  Only UI updates are transmitted to the client.  If you want to get selective with the notifications you can implement *MediatR* - see https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR